# why does my image roll over behave this way?

Tags: php, javascript

My image roll over works... But only one way.

```
function heartOver(id)
{

    if(document.getElementById('heart' + id).src == 'images/heart.png');
    {
        parent.document.getElementById('heart' + id).src = 'images/unheart.png';
    }

    if(document.getElementById('heart' + id).src == 'images/unheart.png');
    {
        parent.document.getElementById('heart' + id).src = 'images/heart.png';
    }   

}


<img src="images/heart.png" id="heart'.$row['id'].'" alt="Love! width="16" height="16" border="0" onmouseover="heartOver'."('$row[id]')".'; return true;" onmouseout="heartOver'."('$row[id]')".'; return true;">
```

If i comment out either of the IF statements the other will work but they wont work together...

Note: Tried this with a `else if` no luck.

Figured it out... Duh: i have if ( ) ; No ; after if...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put an else between them - otherwise when the first if evaluates as true, it will cause the second if to be evaluated as true also!

Here's a simplified example which also checks the assumption that the img element even exists:

```
var img=document.getElementById('heart' + id);
if (img)
{
    if(img.src == 'images/heart.png')
    {
        img.src = 'images/unheart.png';
    }
    else if(img.src == 'images/unheart.png')
    {
        img.src = 'images/heart.png';
    }
} 
else
{
     alert("Ooooh! No heart"+id+" element found!");
}
```

Comment: then you did something wrong - it's definitely the *major* problem

Comment: in your original you refer to parent.document inside the if block, was that intentional? I've simplified my example to eliminate that possible mistake.

Comment: Then alert(img.src) to see what the value actually is!

Comment: Yes the parent.document is intentional but not necessary. Tried it without parent. still no luck.

Comment: and alert(id), maybe it's not what you're expecting, and thus you don't actually find an img element at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
<img src="images/heart.png" id="heart'.$row['id'].'" alt="Love! width="16" height="16" border="0" onmouseover="heartOver'."('$row[id]')".'; return true;" onmouseout="heartOver'."('$row[id]')".'; return true;">
```

Try with this:

```
<img src="images/heart.png" id="heart<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt="Love!" width="16" height="16" border="0" onmouseover="heartOver(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" onmouseout="heartOver(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
```